# Can I use LESS to give elements a class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

I have a table that looked like this:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col_1</th>
            <th>Col_2</th>
            <th>Level</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Value_1_1</td>
            <td>Value_1_2</td>
            <td>Success</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Value_2_1</td>
            <td>Value_2_2</td>
            <td>Error</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The `table` class comes from bootstrap. I have a JavaScript snippet that runs through the rows and applies a `danger` class (also from bootstrap) to any rows containing error text.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr td:contains('Error')").parent().addClass("danger");
});
```

This all worked fine. The table was styled like a bootstrap table, and rows containing error messages were styled correctly.

Then I added another table to my website. I started realizing that I was repeating myself in many places, so I consolidated. I removed the class from the table and instead declared it in a less file, like this:

```
@import "bootstrap/index";

table {
    .table();
}
```

After this change, my tables remain styled like bootstrap tables, but no longer have the actual `table` class. This means that my error rows are no longer styled correctly. Bootstrap's style sheet is specifically looking for `.table > tbody > tr > td.danger`, but my `table` no longer has a class of `table`.

What is the best way to make my table actually have a class of `table`?

I know that I can dynamically add classes to elements via JavaScript (as shown above), but that has the downside that when content is added to the page, I have to invoke the script again. I actually want to get rid of the JavaScript snippet above and replace it with something that works better for dynamic content (for example, an error log that is updated in real-time without refreshing the page using SignalR).

Comment: No you can't, you need javascript to add or remove classnames on elements.

Comment: Why not just add the table class to the tables you need the styling for? Class names are meant to be repeated throughout html markup, they are not unique identifiers. Only id's shouldn't be repeated.

Comment: @JamesIves I'm trying to avoid repeating myself, but if the standard for CSS classes is to repeat yourself then I guess I'll just do that. Thanks for the advice.